# Cocoa/Swift 3.0 replacement for NSNumberFormatter.isPartialStringValid

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3

In a Swift Cocoa app for macOS I inherited from NSNumberFormatter and have overridden isPartialStringValid. After migrating to Swift 3.0 I now have to subclass NumberFormatter and I get the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass". With what could I replace the method?

```
override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>>?) -> Bool { ... }
```

Comment: should be `override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {`

Comment: BTW you should be subclassing NumberFormatter

Comment: True, I am now subclassing NumberFormatter, and it seems there is no method isPartialStringValid anymore?! At least xcode shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I typed `isPartialS...` inside a subclass of `NumberFormatter`, Xcode suggested this:

```
override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String,
                                   newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?,
                                   errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    //...
}
```

Seems your method header has extraneous `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`.

Comment: I just clarified the question, with swift 3 I am now subclassing NumberFormatter instead of NSNumberFormatter, and xcode tells me there is no method isPartialStringValid anymore.

Comment: I also fixed the class name, and I'm sure my Xcode (8 8A218a) have suggested me the method shown above (subclassing `NumberFormatter`), and compiles without error.

Comment: I just installed other updates+reboot, now the isPartialStringValid method with a new signature is shown